# Node.js - calling require caches file - but what if you call 'new'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

if you have a simple javascript file `foo.js` like so:

```
function doSomething (){
console.log('done');
}

module.exports = doSomething;
```

if this file/module is required, it will get cached (any information about this online that you could point me to would be great).

so, in another JS file we have:

```
var foo1 = require('foo'); // yup
```

and in yet another file we have:

```
var foo2 = require('foo'); // points to same cache as foo1
```

but what happens with the cache when we call:

```
var foo3 = new foo2();  // doesn't point to same cache as foo2 and foo1?
```

I assume a new copy of something is created, but what exactly happens beneath the surface?
I am wondering this because I want to know how robust a particular singleton pattern is in JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you think calling a loaded function would affect module loader's cache? :)